# How to add Pin-It button to Ajax Masonry Grid

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, pinterest

I just discovered that the "Save" Pin button won't work when images are loaded into an Ajax masonry grid. Is there a way around this issue? I've looked at other posts on Stackoverflow and none of the code works for my site.

I am using Wordpress - with an Ajax masonry grid to load images. The images do not pull up when you click the "Save" button. Only a heavy worded, non-image box.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[image: screenshot of pin app when clicked]